# Proper JFrame components for viewing data entered, and viewing layout correctly on load

Tags: java, css, swing

As of right now I have all my labels and input fields stacked up the center of the `JFrame`.

When I run the program the program, the label Business Name appears top center and nothing else appears till I resize the window...

Can anyone tell me why it does this and how to fix it?

Also I would like to add a area to the left side of the `JFrame` that will display the contact when you click save, what type of component would I use to do this?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends JFrame {
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;
    private JTextField fieldBN;
    private JTextField fieldFN;
    private JTextField fieldLN;
    private JTextField fieldP;
    private JTextField fieldE;
    private JTextField fieldA;
    private JTextField aLine2;
    private JTextField fieldW;
    private JLabel labelBN;
    private JLabel labelFN;
    private JLabel labelLN;
    private JLabel labelP;
    private JLabel labelE;
    private JLabel labelA;
    private JLabel labelW;
    private JButton buttonS;

    // Constructor:
    public Driver() {       
        gui();      
    }

    public void gui() {
        f = new JFrame("Contact Book");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(900,800); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();  

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    c.gridx = 100;
    c.gridy = 0;
    labelBN = new JLabel ("Business Name");
    p.add(labelBN, c);  

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 0;
    fieldBN = new JTextField(10);
    p.add(fieldBN, c);

    c.gridx = 100;
    c.gridy = 10;
    labelFN= new JLabel ("First Name");
    p.add(labelFN, c);      

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 10;
    fieldFN = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldFN, c);

    c.gridx = 100;
    c.gridy = 20;
    labelLN= new JLabel ("Last Name");
    p.add(labelLN, c);      

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 20;
    fieldLN = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldLN, c);

    c.gridx = 100;
    c.gridy = 30;
    labelP = new JLabel ("Phone Number");
    p.add(labelP, c);

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 30;
    fieldP = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldP, c);

    c.gridx = 100;
    c.gridy = 40;
    labelE = new JLabel ("Email");
    p.add(labelE, c);

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 40;
    fieldE = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldE, c);

    c.gridx = 100;
    c.gridy = 50;                           
    labelA = new JLabel ("Address");
    p.add(labelA, c);

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 50;
    fieldA = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldA, c);
    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 60;
    aLine2 = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(aLine2, c);

    c.gridx = 100;
    c.gridy = 70;
    labelW = new JLabel ("Website");
    p.add(labelW, c);

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 70;
    fieldW = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldW, c);

    c.gridx = 110;
    c.gridy = 80;
    buttonS = new JButton("Save");
    p.add(buttonS, c);

      //    Window Listeners
      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

      }
        ); 
           } // End Gui

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          new Driver();
       } // End main Method

       } // End class Driver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probable cause is right here...

```
public void gui() {
    f = new JFrame("Contact Book");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(900,800); // default size is 0,0
```

You're calling `setVisible` to early.

The simple solution is to call `setVisible` once you've set the frame up the way you want...

```
public void gui() {
    f = new JFrame("Contact Book");
    // Add everything to the frame...
    // pack the frame for better cross platform support
    f.pack();
    // Make it visible
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, extending from `JFrame` and then creating an instance of `JFrame` is very confusing.  Generally, you shouldn't need to extend from `JFrame`, just keep creating an instance as you need.

You should also take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

For example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            new Driver();
       }
    });
} // End main Method
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That makes sense. I read the Initial Threads thing and I am not really understanding that.. Would you mind putting it in to context for me? Also what type of component should I use to display the saved input in the right side of the frame?

Comment: What does the "saved input" consist of?

Comment: I want to take the data and then print it in a box. So when you add data to each field and hit save it will immediately print in a window placed in the Jframe.

Comment: You could consider using a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)